# Generating a random default screen on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

One of the prerequisites within Xcode is setting the 'Default' and 'Default@2x' images for when the iPhone app loads up.

Is it all possible to have a number of Default screens made, inserted into the project in png format and each time the app is loaded, choose a random default screen to use?

Comment: I'd suggest a more specific question: Is is possible at runtime to change the Default image? If you can then adding randomness is trivial, and including it in your question only makes it harder to answer.

Comment: I appreciate you trolling the question. However, answers below proved satisfactory. Thanks

Comment: It was only meant as friendly advice - I apologize if I came off as aloof. I just find that generally, asking the simplest possible question will lead to more and better answers, since it's easier for others to understand what you're asking (I was expecting something rather different based on the title).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot change Default.png. Once the app is shipped - it's "set in stone". Until the next release, that is. The reason is simple (and same why you can't change apps icon). App's bundle is read-only. It is made read only because it is signed by you and by apple. Modifying the contents of the bundle would invalidate the signature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eimantas, I suspected as much.  Just had a nice idea for my next app, but I shall implement it through different means. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

You can change the default screen in iOS (at least after first launch) by setting <kbd>UILaunchImageFile</kbd> property in the info.plist, and then writing a new image to the Documents folder.

eg.

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
<string>../Documents/NewDefault.png</string>
```

then write your random splash to `/Documents/NewDefault.png`.

---

Seems i have to be more prescriptive... I am not suggesting you modify anything in your app bundle at runtime, as has been said, that cannot occur.

But because the `/Documents` folder sits next to the `.app` folder, you can set the `UILaunchImageFile` via a relative path, and then put a file at the path specified when the app runs.

Comment: Is this tried and checked?  From what I know, this file (info.plist) is STILL read-only.

Comment: Yes we have done this. You are not writing to the info.plist, you are writing to the Documents folder.

Comment: how can you """overriding UILaunchImageFile property in the info.plist""" without writing into info.plist?

Comment: You set UILaunchImageFile property at build time

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the startup screen without rebuilding the app. It's name is either hardcoded in info plist or is set to the default value of "Default.png" if nothing is set in the plist.

Since both the image file and plist file are inside app's bundle which is digitally signed, even if you could change any of them (you can't as it's read-only), your app's signature would invalidate and crash on non-jailbroken devices.