# Random Image for Launch Screen

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

I have 3 different images I'd like to use Launch Screen.

I've added a `UIImageView` in the `Launchscreen.storyboard`

And I was thinking I could use a simple Switch statement with a randomizer to select the image:

```
var random = arc4random_uniform(3) //returns 0 to 2 randomly

  switch random {
    case 0:
        launchImageView.image = UIImage(named: "splash1.jpg")
    case 1:
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "splash2.jpg")
    default:
        /myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "splash3.jpg")      }
```

However I'm not really sure where to implement the code as the `viewDidLoad` will not work.

Comment: Good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10369488/1186243 read the comments also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the **UILaunchImageFile** by a relative path and then put an image at the path and use your random.

For example you change the launchscreen after launching by setting UILaunchImageFile property in the info.plist. You would then write a random image to the Documents folder.

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
<string>../Documents/image.png</string>
```