# Random launch-image for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am currently working on a react native project.  One of the requirement is to show random launch images on startup on both Android and iOS.

Do you guys know how can this be achieved ?   I saw the solution  ( [Random Image for Launch Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535742/random-image-for-launch-screen) ) , however, I am not that good in iOS/Android.

Can you please guide me into achieving this ? Is there a better solution in react-native itself ?

Thanks and Kind Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to use a temporary screen to show the splashscreen on react-native side.

On native side, I will be using a image icon.

so that when the app launches, you will see the icon followed by the temp screen followed by your Home screen.